# How to navigate into a collections in collections with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a `collection of collection` into a `variable`. I try to manage data into this variable but it's not working.

```
// User.php
public function projects()
 {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class,'time_entries')
                                    ->withPivot('hours');
 }
```

```
// Project.php
public function users()
 {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'time_entries')
        ->withPivot('hours');
 }
```

```
/// TimeEntries.php

public function user() 
 {
        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Model\User' );
 }

public function project() 
 {
        return $this->belongsTo( 'App\Model\Project','project_id' );
 }
```

A User can make a lot of time entries and he can participate to a lot of projects. Project can have a lot of time entries.

I try this :

```
$users = User::with('projects')->get();
        foreach ($users$users = User::with('projects')->get();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            foreach($user->projects() as $a) {
                dump ($a);
            }
        }
```

and i got

```
false
```

dump of $user :

```
User {#715 ▼
  #table: "users"
  #connection: "redmine"
  #with: array:1 [▶]
  #fillable: array:19 [▶]
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:19 [▶]
  #original: array:19 [▶]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: array:2 [▼
    "projectrecap" => Collection {#714 ▼
      #items: []
    }
    "projects" => Collection {#1414 ▼
      #items: array:11 [▼
        0 => Project {#17329 ▶}
        1 => Project {#17338 ▶}
        2 => Project {#17339 ▶}
        3 => Project {#17340 ▶}
        4 => Project {#17341 ▶}
        5 => Project {#17342 ▶}
        6 => Project {#17343 ▶}
        7 => Project {#17344 ▶}
        8 => Project {#17345 ▶}
        9 => Project {#17346 ▶}
        10 => Project {#17347 ▶}
      ]
    }
  ]
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

I would like, for all user see all project he worked and the sum of hours he worked on.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a typo.

```
foreach($user->projects as $a) {
    dump ($a);
}
```

Make sure to remove the parenthesys `()`